Trying to classify a quotient group

Consider a $3 \times 3$ matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal, an $a_{12}$ entry from integers, and $a_{13}$ and $a_{23}$ entries from real numbers. What's the quotient of this group with the Heisenberg group over integers?

Consider the map $\phi: G \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\phi\left( \!\! \begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
0 & 1 & a_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \!\! \right) 
= (a_{13} \bmod \mathbb{Z},\, a_{23} \bmod \mathbb{Z}).
$$
This map has the required kernel but it is not homomorphism. Any other idea?

The Heinsenberg group over integers is not a normal subgroup of $G$, so the question does not make sense.  If $[a,b,c]=\begin{pmatrix}1 & a & b \cr 0 & 1 & c\cr 0 & 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$, then $[1,0,\sqrt{2}][1,1,0][1,0,\sqrt{2}]^{-1}=[1,1-\sqrt{2},0]$.

Did you mean the subgroup with $a_{12},a_{23}\in\mathbb{Z}$? That one is normal, but properly contains the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{Z}$.
